# Retrieving attributes from AD (Python 3)

Tags: python

I'm trying to connect to AD in order to retrieve attributes for a user, but I can't get it to connect.

Code:

```
import ldap3
s = ldap3.Server(srvaddr)
c = ldap3.Connection(s, auto_bind = True)
c.search('o=user', '(objectClass=*)', attributes = ['sn', 'l'])
print(c.result)
```

Error:

```
In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection. (LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8)
```

Everything I've found so far related to this error is based on ldap and Python 2, I don't know how to fix it here.

Comment: What's weird is I know the bind is done successfully because if I specify a user/password it tells me invalid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any credential, so you are performing an anonymous bind. In this case ad does not return any search. You must pass a valid user and password in the Connection object.

Bye,
Giovanni